# Aggregating in R with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataset with the following information:

```
> Column1 Column2 Sum 
a         b        50 
b         a         7 
c         a         1
d         e         8
c         a         2
```

I want to aggregate to get this result:

```
> Column1 Column2 Sum 
a         b        57 
c         a         3
d         e         8
```

Because `a-b` its the same that `b-a`

Any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jaap i didnt find this information before. could you send me that link? thanks

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+apply+sort+aggregate+sum)

Comment: i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360148/take-sum-of-a-variable-if-combination-of-values-in-two-other-columns-are-unique

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` after `sort` ing the first two columns by row

```
df1[1:2] <- t(apply(df1[1:2], 1, sort))
aggregate(Sum~., df1, FUN = sum)
```

---

Or using `pmax/pmin`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Col1 = pmin(Column1, Column2), Col2 = pmax(Column1, Column2)) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(Sum))
```

Comment: Is there any performance improvement doing `t(apply(df1[1:2], 1, sort))` instead of `apply(df1[1:2], 2, sort)`?